# How to apply a different backgroundcolor for GWT decoratedPopupPanel?

Tags: java, gwt, popup, ui-design

```
final DecoratedPopupPanel infoPopup = new DecoratedPopupPanel(true);
    infoPopup.setWidget(new Label("Table below displays the total number of users for each application for the selected time range."));
    infoPopup.setWidth("150px");

    inImage.addMouseOverHandler(new MouseOverHandler(){
        public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent arg0){
            int left = inImage.getAbsoluteLeft() + 10;
            int top = inImage.getAbsoluteTop() + 10;
           infoPopup.setPopupPosition(left, top);

            // Show the popup
            infoPopup.show();
        }

    });

    inImage.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler(){
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent arg0){
           //hide
            infoPopup.hide();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by creating your own custom styling using CSS.

By default `DecoratedPopupPanel` use `gwt-DecoratedPopupPanel` style defined in *clean.css*.

```
.gwt-DecoratedPopupPanel .popupMiddleCenter {
    padding: 3px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

---

Create your own style and just update the *background* color property and apply the style on it as shown below:

CSS:

```
.myPopupPanelStyle {
  background: #0000FF;
}
```

JAVA:

```
infoPopup.setStyleName("myPopupPanelStyle");
```